# Projective Modules over the Ring of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, projective-module

Let $ R = \mathbb{R}[ \cos x, \sin x] $ and consider the ideal $ \langle 1 - \cos x, \sin x\rangle $. Is this ideal a projective module over $R$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{R}[\cos x, \sin x]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ which is known as being a Dedekind domain, so all ideals are projective.

Comment: I'm interested to know where I can find an explanation of why it is Dedekind. Thanks!

Comment: It's an interesting example that I had not seen in detail before. I imagine all commutative algebraists must be familiar with it!

Comment: @rschwieb, you can see it here, http://math.colorado.edu/~ravi1033/notes/pre08/pdf/real_polynomials_on_unit_circle_dedekind.pdf
I already read that before this post, expecting some straight forward solution, but on your reply I found that it is again the same complex manipulations :-)